# How to compare array element?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose I have an `array` having `elements` `"am","john","rosa","freedom"`. I want to `compare` these elements and result would be the `word` and the `size of the longest word`. I am using `objective C`.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137839/comparing-arrays-in-objective-c

Comment: Could you precise : what kind of array (C style array or NSArray) ?
Rem :comparing two element always return a single value (NSOrderDescending, NSOrderAscending or NSOrderedSame).

Comment: Are `elements` instances of `NSString` or some other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a "built-in" way of doing this, however you can use `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` and create a category on `NSString` to provide a `lengthCompare:` method.

```
// NSString+LengthCompare.h
#import NSString.h
@interface NSString (LengthComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)lengthCompare:(NSString *)aString;
@end

// NSString+LengthCompare.m
#import NSString+LengthCompare.h
@implememtation NSString (LengthComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)lengthCompare:(NSString *)aString
{        
    if ([self length] < [aString length]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ([self length] > [aString length]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
@end
```

Now you can sort an of strings *in ascending order* using `lengthCompare:`

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"am", @"john", @"rosa", @"freedom", nil];
NSArray *arraySortedByStringLength = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(lengthCompare:)];

NString *shortestWord = [[arraySortedByStringLength objectAtIndex:0] retain];
NSLog(@"shortest word, %@ has length %d", shortestWord, [shortestWord length];
[shortestWord release];

NString *longestWord = [[arraySortedByStringLength lastObject] retain];
NSLog(@"Longest word, %@ has length %d", longestWord, [longestWord length];

[longestWord release];
```

Comment: If you're only going to do it once, you could also use -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:], which uses a block instead of a selector.  Then you don't have to declare a method that only gets called once.

Comment: Good alternative however blocks are limited to iOS4 and above.

Comment: tag is [iphone]. on the Mac, blocks were introduced in 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Comment: updated code to correctly select the longest word given the sortedArrayUsingSelector: returns an array sorted in *ascending* order

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classical logic exercise or is it something I miss in your question ?

```
int longestWordIndex = 0;
NSUInteger longestWordSize = 0;
for (int i=0 ; i<[nameArray count] ; i++) {
  NSString* element = (NSString*)[nameArray objectAtindex:i];
  if([element lenght] > longestWordSize) {
    longestWordSize = [element lenght];
    longestWordIndex = i;
  } 
}
NSLog("Longest word is %@ with size of :%d", [nameArray objectAtIndex:longestWordIndex], longestWordSize);
```

Comment: well thanx,I know this solution. But this is a lay man solution. If you can tell me any inbuilt methods which is available in objecive C.

Comment: Yep, I thought so.  You could probably mess up with indexesOfObjectsPassingTest but you will have to call it twice anyway. 
No other idea

Answer (score 0):

I'll add one more approach to the two above -- use a block to do the body of your iteration.

```
__block NSUInteger longestWordSize = -1; // Make sure at least one object will be longer.
__block NSUInteger longestWordIndex;

[nameArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id currentWord, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([currentWord length] > longestWordSize) {
        longestWordSize = [currentWord length];
        longestWordIndex = index;
    }
}];

NSLog("Longest word is %@ with size of :%d", [nameArray objectAtIndex:longestWordIndex], longestWordSize);
```

Edit: The max and index have to be of storage type `__block` so they can be changed from inside the block.