# Accessing image with a tag in UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to compare two images that is stored as an array of UIImageView.

How can I access a particular image through a tag?

EDIT: If images were stored as separate UIImageView I would have compared

```
imageView1.image == imageView2.image;
```

But since it is stored as an array I'm confused to access it. Ideally it would be

```
someArray[1].image == someArray[2].image;
```

But it is not viable.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to access it through the tag you set or you are talking about the index of an array?

Comment: Whatever applicable. I just wanted to get an access to an image

Comment: check this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137839/comparing-arrays-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:someTag];
```

Just send viewWithTag to any instance of UIView and you'll get the View with that tag back.

Comment: Point of clarification: Not any UIView, but any superview of the view in question. (or super-super view, etc.) It won't work if the UIView you query is a sibling of your image view.

Comment: David, remember that lots of total newbies read SO. You shouldn't make any statements that can be misinterpreted due to a lack of prior knowledge. Even if the OP gets it, the 50 other newbies who read the thread won't.

Comment: I'm Not knocking newbies either. We were all beginners once. (Of course there was no such thing as the internet when I was a newbie, but that's a different story.)